# Spring 4 @Transactional and @Aspect

Tags: spring, transactions, aspectj

I have an interceptor class which monitors the creation of objects. I want this interceptor to be called before the actual create method of services to inject current user / date.

```
/**
 * Author: plalonde
 * When: 2015-03-04
 */
@Aspect
public class IdentityInterceptor {
    /**
     * Injection de l'usagé actuellement en session dans l'entité.
     *
     * @param entity L'entité dans laquelle les informations de l'usagé doivent être injectée.
     */
    @Before("execution(* com.t3e.persistence.service.CrudService.create(..)) && args(entity)")
    public void giveOwnership(final TraceableDto entity) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        entity.setCreationUserId(authentication.getName());
        entity.setCreationDate(new Date());
        entity.setLastModificationUserId(authentication.getName());
        entity.setLastModificationDate(new Date());
    }
}


/**
 * Author: plalonde
 * When: 2015-04-22
 */
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class LocalWatsonLicenseService implements WatsonLicenseService {
    @Autowired
    private WatsonLicenseRepository repository;

    /**
     * Création d'une licence.
     *
     * @param watsonLicenseDetails Le détails de la licence à créer.
     * @return L'instance de la licence mise à jour.
     */
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public WatsonLicenseDetails create(final WatsonLicenseDetails watsonLicenseDetails) {
        return repository.create(watsonLicenseDetails);
    }

}

/**
 * Author: plalonde
 * When: 2015-04-22
 */
public interface WatsonLicenseService extends CrudService<WatsonLicenseDetails> {
}
```

My interceptor never gets called and I am wondering if it's because the service's method are @Transctional?

It looks like Aspect is well configured, because I have other services method where everything works like expected.

I tried looking for documentation, but I get only posts on handling transactions with Aspect, but it's not my case.

Should my wrapped method return the updated value or be passed in the pointcut and process it?

[EDIT]

This is how the interceptor is declared

```
/**
 * Author: plalonde
 * When: 2015-04-22
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class DatabaseConfig {
    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dmds = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
        dmds.setDriverClassName(driver);

        return dmds;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate configureTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public IdentityInterceptor createInterceptor() {
        return new IdentityInterceptor();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is WatsonLicenseDetails defined?

Comment: And you are doing nothing with the aspect. You need to tell Spring that you want to enable aspectj for this add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your configuration.

Comment: That was it, forgot the annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in M.Deinum comment, I forgot the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in my configuration class, this fixed the problem.

Will flag this as the right answer when allowed.